# Django Paginator: where does paginator modify SQL query adding LIMIT/OFFSET?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to hook up to django pagination system and got a low-level question.

I've been digging through the code of [Manager](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/manager.py), [Queryset](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py) and [Paginator](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/paginator.py), but I can't find the place, where `Paginator` makes [SQLCompiler](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py) set limit and offset on SQL query, forcing it to return only a part of queryset.

Can you find that place? Cause it's not in the code of Paginator itself.

Here's an example of SQL, generated by paginator:

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>>
>>> paginator = Paginator(Myobject.objects.filter(foreign_key='URS0000416056'), 1)
>>> for myobject in paginator.page(1):
>>>     print myobject
Myobject object
>>>
>>> print connection.queries
[{u'time': u'0.903', u'sql': u'SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "xref" WHERE "xref"."upi" = \'URS0000416056\''}, {u'time': u'0.144', u'sql': u'SELECT "xref"."id", "xref"."dbid", "xref"."ac", "xref"."created", "xref"."last", "xref"."upi", "xref"."version_i", "xref"."deleted", "xref"."timestamp", "xref"."userstamp", "xref"."version", "xref"."taxid" FROM "xref" WHERE "xref"."upi" = \'URS0000416056\' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1'}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the links to the source, they let me dig up the details.

`Paginator` uses slice notation on the wrapped queryset when constructing `Page` instances:

```
        return self._get_page(self.object_list[bottom:top], number, self)
```

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/paginator.py#L57

Here `object_list` is a queryset despite the name if you used the `Paginator` on a queryset in the first place.

Querysets, in turn, implement slice notation in their `__getitem__` method:

```
            qs.query.set_limits(start, stop)
```

The slice-specific handling starts at https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L260 currently.

The query class turns those into low and high mark attributes on the query in the [`set_limits`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/sql/query.py#L1504) method:

```
def set_limits(self, low=None, high=None):
    """
    Adjust the limits on the rows retrieved. Use low/high to set these,
    as it makes it more Pythonic to read and write. When the SQL query is
    created, convert them to the appropriate offset and limit values.
    Apply any limits passed in here to the existing constraints. Add low
    to the current low value and clamp both to any existing high value.
    """
    if high is not None:
        if self.high_mark is not None:
            self.high_mark = min(self.high_mark, self.low_mark + high)
        else:
            self.high_mark = self.low_mark + high
    if low is not None:
        if self.high_mark is not None:
            self.low_mark = min(self.high_mark, self.low_mark + low)
        else:
            self.low_mark = self.low_mark + low

    if self.low_mark == self.high_mark:
        self.set_empty()
```

(That's the current implementation as of September 2017, it may change in the future.)

Low and high marks in turn get turned into LIMIT and OFFSET query params in the `SQLCompiler`s [`as_sql`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py#L534) method:

```
        if with_limits:
            if self.query.high_mark is not None:
                result.append('LIMIT %d' % (self.query.high_mark - self.query.low_mark))
            if self.query.low_mark:
                if self.query.high_mark is None:
                    val = self.connection.ops.no_limit_value()
                    if val:
                        result.append('LIMIT %d' % val)
                result.append('OFFSET %d' % self.query.low_mark)
```